# Ortho Viewport is rendering some hidden/covert Edges in Edit Mode

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

For some reason, part of the Edges that are behind Geometry, still get drawn in the scene. The object neither has XRay enabled  nor is "limit selection to visible" active. "Backface Culling" also seems not to be the problem. This only appears in Ortho View and not in Perspective View. Any ideas?[image]
Perpective View:
[image]

[image]

Comment: backface culling ?

Comment: thx, but didn't help either.

Comment: can you or upload your model or show a screen shot with both ortho and perspective views ?

Comment: Uploaded the Blend and Perp View

Comment: FYI, if that gives you an idea, if you separate a face, this face is ok after that. So this seems to be related to the object itself.

Comment: Really? If i create a new object in my scene, eg a cylinder, this object also has this weird behavior. So i think sth with the scene/blend got wrong. Only solution to "fix" it, is by exporting all objects to a new blend file with append. but it would be nice if there is a smoother solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the clipping. I'm not sure whether it's a bug or not but lowering the end value solves the issue.[image: your clip value] Your clip value
[image: lower clip value]
lower clip value

Comment: It's not a bug (this time  :)  ). Depth Information (which is required for clipping geometry correctly) is stored as a grayscale buffer with a limited amount of 'color' depth. So, the distance between near and far clip is being divided by the maximum number of greyscale values which can be stored. Each of the values corresponds to a slice of the scene. If the values are far apart, each pixel contains more of the 3D scene so to speak, resulting in the camera not knowing any more what is in front and what is behind. It's the same issue as with Depth Shadow maps. Same logic, different outcome.

Comment: It is also worth noting that for perspective view, these values are not mapped lineary, the closer the object to the camera, the more precise the depth info (actually, the camera does a non-linear, perspective mapping of (x, y, z) to the screens (x, y, depth)). Orthographic view is a linear transformation, so those discrete values are evenly placed across that huge range.